# Displaying specific rows that have a key word in the cells in a csv (python)

Tags: python, filtering

I have a CSV file that is an expense report such as:

```
day       amount    category
monday    1.00      food
tuesday   2.00      entertainment
wednesday 3.00      drinks
...       ...       ...
```

I want to write a code that ask the user to select a category and then display all the information that the user chooses I.e:

User chooses food:

```
Day     Amount   Category
Monday  1.00     food
Friday  3.50     food
```

So far I have:

```
category = input("Input the category you wish to view (Beverages, Food, Travel, Entertainment, Clothing): ")
    if not category in expense_report:
        print("Please enter a valid category")
```

but not sure what to do next to filter out what the user chooses.

Answer (score 0):

Say the name of your csv file is data, you could use:
`print(data[data.Category == category])`

Which would display all the rows and columns of the csv file where the Category matches the category entered by the user.

I would assume using a library such as pandas would make this more efficient.